# C# Mock using Moq

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I have a Employee class with one method which is not implemented

```
namespace Employee
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public virtual DateTime getDateOfJoining(int id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to mock this, and I'm expecting the method to return current DateTime.

```
namespace Employee.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void getJoiningDateMock()
        {
            var employee = new Mock<Employee>();
            employee.Setup(x => x.getDateOfJoining(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns((int x) => DateTime.Now);

            var objEmp = new Employee();

            Assert.AreEqual(DateTime.Now, employee.getDateOfJoining(1));
        }
    }
}
```

The way I'm invoking Mock is incorrect. What am I missing here, specifically how would I write AssertEquals?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the end goal?

Comment: Why are you expecting two different `DateTime.Now` objects to be equal? Use `DateTime.Today` or the same variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below only confirms that the mock behaves as it was setup.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 {
    [TestMethod]
    public void getJoiningDateMock() {
        //Arrange
        var expected = DateTime.Now;
        var employeeMock = new Mock<Employee>();
        employeeMock
            .Setup(x => x.getDateOfJoining(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(expected);

        var objEmp = employeeMock.Object;

        //Act
        var actual = objEmp.getDateOfJoining(1);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Reference : [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)